# C++ Function pointer error

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to make a source code to work

```
extern "C" {
    typedef LRESULT (__stdcall *NRI_PM_CALLBACK)(WPARAM, LPARAM);
}

LRESULT OnPaymentManagerMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int type = (wParam >> 4) & 0x0F;
    int device = wParam & 0x0F;
    //cstr.Format("** Msg **[ %d %d %d ]", type, device, lParam);
    //handle message here
    return lParam;
}

NRI_PM_CALLBACK callback = &OnPaymentManagerMessage; //error on this line
```

Error:a value of type "LRESULT (*)(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)" cannot be used to initialized an entity of type "NRI_PM_CALLBACK"

I am running this in Visual Studio Express 2012

Any ideas why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `OnPaymentManagerMessage()` a `__stdcall` function:

```
LRESULT __stdcall OnPaymentManagerMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
/* ... */
```

`__cdecl` is the default for the compiler (though a compiler option can change that).

Comment: And `extern "C"` (although I think VC++ ignores this in favor of its proprietary extensions).

Comment: Thank you Michael, I love you :D